# Simple result on $(X_n)$ sequence of random variables uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$

Tags: probability

Suppose $(X_n)$ is a sequence of random variables uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Let $(Y_n)$ be the sequence defined by $Y_n = \operatorname{max}_{k \in \{1, \dots, n\}}X_k$. Here, I try to prove that $Y_n$ converges in probability to $1$. For $\varepsilon > 0$, the result is trivial is $\varepsilon \geq 1$, so we assume $\varepsilon < 1$. Then

$$P(|Y_n - 1|>\varepsilon) = P(Y_n \leq 1-\varepsilon) = P(\bigcap_{k=1^n}\{X_k \leq 1-\varepsilon\}) = (1-\varepsilon)^n \to 0$$

It seems to me that in this answer, I assumed that $(X_n)$ is an independent sequence, which I don't know if is necessarily the case. Is this proof correct?

Comment: If $X_n$ are not independent, the worst case being they are equal, then $Y_n$ would not converge in prob to $1$, but to the uniform distribution on the unit interval instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct under independence. The conclusion fails in general. For example, if $X_i=X_1$ for all $i$ the $Y_n=X_n$ which does not converge to $1$ in probability.